# Why am I getting Error: Run-time error 1004.Excel

Tags: excel

> Application defined or object defined error.

What can I do? It is impossible to fix this problem.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-14, -4).Range("A1:F11").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveCell.Offset(3, -7).Range("A1:F11").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Range("A1:F2"), CopyToRange:= _
    ActiveCell, Unique:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: Sub ÌàêðîÑòóä()
'
' ÌàêðîÑòóä Ìàêðîñ
' àâòîìàòè÷åñêèé ìàêðîñ ïî òàáë.Ñòóäåíò
'
' Ñî÷åòàíèå êëàâèø: Ctrl+w
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-14, -4).Range("A1:F11").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, -7).Range("A1:F11").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Range("A1:F2"), CopyToRange:= _
        ActiveCell, Unique:=False
End Sub

Comment: What is the active cell when you hit this part of the code.  Unless it is at least E15 lower and to the right it will error.

Comment: When you recorded the macro, you used relative reference, which means wherever the activecell was at the time of recording would have to be where the activecell would have to be when you run the code. Longer version of @ScottCraner explanation.